# Is it possible to only increment a Lead field only in specific instances?

Tags: leads, assignment-rules

Currently we have 2 custom fields on Lead. Lead Number, which is just an auto incrementing number. And then a Round Robin ID which is an equation.

```
MOD(VALUE({!Lead_Number__c}) ,3) +1
```

We use this Round Robin ID to assign the lead to a specific salesperson with our Lead Assignment rules.

Only problem is we have one lead source that is the best and hottest leads. The sales guys want those leads to be assigned Round Robin **independant** of the other leads.

And that is the problem. Their turn in the Round Robin is being used up on an ok lead. So what is currently happening:

```
Best Lead Source - assigned to Salesguy 1
Ok Lead Source   - assigned to Salesguy 2
Ok Lead Source   - assigned to Salesguy 3
Best Lead Source - assigned to Salesguy 1
```

But we want this to happen:

```
Best Lead Source - assigned to Salesguy 1
Ok Lead Source   - assigned to Salesguy X (doesn't matter)
Ok Lead Source   - assigned to Salesguy X (doesn't matter)
Best Lead Source - assigned to Salesguy 2
```

Is it possible to make another auto-incrementing field that only increments when the Lead Source is set to something specific?

Or is there a way to setup a workflow to increment a field when another field is set?

I found this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76291/auto-increment-number-based-on-another-field) at asks for something similar but it doesn't even need to be auto-incrementing. Just need it to count up only a certain type of lead.

Comment: Unless you want to write code, no. Odds are, simply letting them fall where they may is probably acceptable. Assuming you can't predict the order of the leads, they will usually fall to sales people approximately evenly over time.

Comment: @sfdcfox I understand the distribution and explained that, but to a sales person, seeing someone get 2 hot leads in a row is intolerable. :) I am not against writing code, however, I was hoping to set it up with system only for maintenance. How would you go about it in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a combination of code and assignment rules to accomplish your goals.

You can do this in just a few steps:

### Custom Settings

Create a custom setting, type List, with whatever name you wish. For each lead source you want to assign specially, you can create a custom value of your choice. In my example, I define the ability to assign a unique, incrementing value per lead source.

### Create Custom Lead Fields

Create a field that will be assigned a numeric value. Create another field that returns the first field's value MOD the number of sales people you want to divvy up for.

### Apex Trigger

Create a trigger on leads to assign a value:

```
trigger AssignByLeadSource on Lead (before insert) {
    // Use row locks to prevent race conditions
    {
        LeadSourceCounters__c[] temp = [SELECT Id FROM LeadSourceCounters__c FOR UPDATE];
    }
    Map<String, LeadSourceCounters__c> counters = LeadSourceCounters__c.getAll().clone();
    for(Lead record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.LeadSource==null) {
            continue;
        }
        if(!counters.containsKey(record.LeadSource)) {
            counters.put(record.LeadSource, new LeadSourceCounters__c(Name=record.LeadSource, Value__c=0));
        }
        counters.get(record.LeadSource).Value__c+=1;
        record.AssignmentId__c = counters.get(record.LeadSource).Value__c;
    }
    upsert counters.values();
}
```

### Assignment Rules

Now, simply use an assignment rule to determine how you'd like to assign leads. For example, you might have entries like this:

- If Lead Source = 'Great Lead Source' AND AssignmentGreatLeadMod = 0, assign to Alice.
- If Lead Source = 'Great Lead Source' AND AssignmentGreatLeadMod = 1, assign to Bob.
- etc...

This design, despite needing code, doesn't need to query the database for existing (lead) records to determine the next owner, can be configured on the fly or even be reset by an administrator, and requires minimal configuration.

I could mention more elaborate answers, like using the platform cache (new in Winter 16), reading public groups/roles/etc to determine order, and query the most recently created leads to determine next person to be assigned, and so on, but this is all overkill. Keep it simple, and you'll get great performance, and your users will be evenly and deterministically assigned leads.

Comment: Great solution @sfdcfox

Comment: However, what is the need to query "temp", since you do not use this anywhere?

Comment: What is LeadSourceCounters__c in your example? I tried to use the name of my Custom List, the field on that custom list, and the custom lead field, and I only get 'Error: Compile Error: sObject type 'Web_Demo_Round_Robin_ID__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. line 4'

Comment: It appears I only created those fields in my production environment. I will fix that now. :)

Comment: @JoshuaDance A Custom Setting of the List variety. See Setup > Develop > Custom Settings. This code is only meant as an example. LeadSourceCounters__c is a custom setting, Value__c is a custom field on the custom setting, type Decimal, large enough to hold a really large value, and AssignmentId__c is a custom lead field used by the formula field that the assignment rules will eventually evaluate.

Comment: I have everything working, but this line `counters.put(record.LeadSource, (new LeadSourceCounters__c(Name=record.LeadSource, Value__c=0)));` throws the error `System.FinalException: Collection is read-only`. Why is the map coming across as read only?

Comment: @JoshuaDance I'll have to revise the code, I think. It's "final" because it came from a "query." Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I asked [the question here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/99727/calling-put-on-map-of-custom-settings-cause-collection-is-read-only-apex-erro) - because I thought it was a simple syntax or parameter error I wasn't getting. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JoshuaDance You have to "clone" it, I found out. I've updated the code for you.

Comment: @sfdcfox using your code and explanations I was able to get this working perfectly in our production. Thanks!