# SOQL query to get greatest value from unique ID or Custom Setting

Tags: soql, customsetting, web2lead, unique-field

trying to figure out the best way to increment a uniqueID value by 1 when leads are inserted into our org.  Our externally required uniqueID is formatted as follows XX-YYYYY, where XX has values of "A1" or "B1" etc., and YYYYY is generally an autonumber like value. Example values: A1-0005 or B2-3412499.

When leads are inserted via different methods (web2lead etc), we'd like to have that YYYYY value incremented by one (YYYYY++).  Assume the XX value for this particular POST is known.

I see two options.  First, can create a Custom Setting and just increment that value as we go.

Or second, can write a SOQL query of following type that gets us greatest value and increments.

```
String HighValue = [SELECT UniqueID FROM Leads WHERE UniqueID 
LIKE "B1%" ORDER BY UniqueID DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1];
```

(Syntax may be incorrect, but idea should be there).

So questions are:

1. Is there a preference for using the Custom Setting solution or the SOQL solution?
2. If the SOQL solution, any advice on the method/syntax
3. Anyone have any better ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Beware of race conditions implementing those solutions, why not simply use an auto number field?

Comment: this may shine some insight: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76291/auto-increment-number-based-on-another-field

Comment: @PepeFloyd interesting, how would this create a race condition? as for autonumber, the format of the field is a string, I suppose you could use two fields - one number and one string,  and then a third formula field to concat them.

Comment: @crop1645 - thanks, was somewhat helpful, we've trended towards the custom setting solution